# Excel Active X Checkbox Uncheck by default

Tags: excel, checkbox

I have this code for an active x check box

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Range("RowBlock2").EntireRow.Hidden = CheckBox2.Value
End Sub
```

[image: [IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/2z5953c.png[/IMG]]

the check boxes have a click sign in them. I don't know why

When I click on them they show the hidden rows.

is there any way to fix the code so the check boxes are not ticked in by default

thank you

I'm sure its something simple but Ive been searching for hours trying to fix this any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Value in the properties window, Right click the checkbox select properties, from the window set the value to true for checked, false for unchecked.

[image]

Comment: I am a bit confused, when the checkbox is unchecked it shows the hidden rows, i need to check it to hide the rows   -   the check sign then remains. This is the problem, any idea how to clear it?