# Unselect All CheckBoxes From Excel Workbook with VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, unselect

I have a workbook with over 100 checkboxes.

They are **form control checkboxes**

I would like to un-select them all at once

that is set them to false.

```
 Sub clearcheck()
 ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Value = False
 End Sub
```

This works for the active sheet. I would like this code to be for the whole workbook

I have tried looking for the code and messing about with clearing the checkboxes but am none the wiser.

I would really appreciate if some one could guide me

thank you

Comment: What kind of checkboxes are those? Form Control or ActiveX Control?

Comment: Well, I [GUESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927090/excel-active-x-checkbox-uncheck-by-default) they are ActiveX. In that case Gary's answer will do the job :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have OLEObject-style (**ActiveX**) checkboxes, then:

```
Sub terranian()
    Dim o As Object
    For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If InStr(1, o.Name, "CheckBox") > 0 Then
            o.Object.Value = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT1:**

If they are **forms checkboxes** , then the following will work:

```
Sub clearcheck()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
            sh.CheckBoxes.Value = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary, many thanks for your answer, the checkboxes are form control and not active x, will this code still work?

Comment: Hi Gary, This works perfectly fine for active x checkboxes in the active sheet. I am looking for one macro when clicked will unselect all the form control checkboxes in the workbook, please advise

Comment: Gary's Student You are my hero!!! Thank you so much Sir , you saved me at least a couple of hours of pulling my hair out, Kudos to you and so very pleased, well done and stack overflow should have more people like you!! :)  : )  : )

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is perfect, but I needed the ability to clear the active sheet OR all check-boxes via buttons for **form checkboxes**. Putting both sub routines inside of one "Module" worked for me. Then I created a button for each action, and mapped to the individual sub-routines.

```
'Uncheck all checkboxes in entire excel workbook
Sub uncheck_all()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
            sh.Checkboxes.Value = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next sh
End Sub

'Uncheck all checkboxes in active sheet
Sub uncheck_active_sheet()
    ActiveSheet.Checkboxes.Value = False
End Sub
```