# Send Email if check box is checked

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to send email mail to the address which is checked 
I have:

1. Check box
2. Column Name
3. Column Email

   ```
   Sub reminder1()

   Dim lRow As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim toList As String
   Dim eSubject As String
   Dim eBody As String

   With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = False
       .EnableEvents = False
       .DisplayAlerts = False
   End With

   Sheets(1).Select
   lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 2 To lRow

       If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then

           Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
           Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
           Cells(i, 5) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time
           Cells(i, 5).Font.Bold = True

           toList = Cells(i, 3)

           eSubject = "Your "

           eBody = "Good Day"

           On Error Resume Next

           With OutMail
               .To = toList
               .CC = ""
               .BCC = ""
               .Subject = eSubject
               .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
               .Display
               .HTMLBody = eBody & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
               '.Send
           End With

           On Error GoTo 0
           Set OutMail = Nothing
           Set OutApp = Nothing 
       End If
       Next i

       ActiveWorkbook.Save

       With Application
           .ScreenUpdating = True
           .EnableEvents = True
           .DisplayAlerts = True
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Problem is that if i check first one it send email to all if not checked it is not sending email even other check boxes are checked

Comment: Your code only looks at one checkbox (Checkbox1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the check boxes. Your current code is hardcoded to check only the first check box, which is the "CheckBox1".

**Instead of:**

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then
'code
end if
```

**Use something like this:**

```
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox"&i-1).Object.Value  = True Then
'code
End If
```

**Alternative**
Instead of a checkbox, use dropdown with true / false
Then use something like this:

```
if cells(i,1).value = True then
'code
end if
```

Comment: i tried to put this ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("CheckBox"&i).Value = True Then but getting RUN TIME ERROR 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: 'If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Checkbox"&i-1).Object.Value  = True Then' its working perfect Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I 'd propose that you loop through all check boxes and try to find the check box which is applicable to the row you are currently on. So, in order to stick with your solution and having a checkbox in each row you need to verify which checkbox applies to the row you are in and see if the checkbox is checked.

```
Sub reminder1()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim toList As String
Dim eSubject As String
Dim eBody As String
Dim oleControl As OLEObject

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Sheets(1).Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
    For Each oleControl In Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects
        If Range(oleControl.TopLeftCell.Address).Row = i Then
            If oleControl.Object.Value = True Then

                Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                Cells(i, 5) = "Mail Sent " & Date + Time
                Cells(i, 5).Font.Bold = True

                toList = Cells(i, 3)

                eSubject = "Your "

                eBody = "Good Day"

                On Error Resume Next

                With OutMail
                    .To = toList
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = eSubject
                    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                    .Display
                    .HTMLBody = eBody & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
                    '.Send
                End With

                On Error GoTo 0
                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Set OutApp = Nothing

            End If
        End If
    Next oleControl 
Next i

ActiveWorkbook.Save

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Note that this code assumes that the top left corner of the checkbox is within the row to which the checkbox applies. If that's not the case then you can also use the `.BottomRightCell.Address` or a mix of the two.
Also note that this code does not verify if there are other shapes on the sheet such as combo boxes or buttons or other things.

Comment: yes check box is in same rows as name and emails but i am getting this    RUN TIME ERROR 438 Object doesn't support this property or method on this line """"If shp.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn And Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address).Row = i Then""" Check box is Cloumn A row 2 to row say 20 and have no other shapes on sheet

Comment: @kzhel-farmer: I forgot that you are using ActiveX controls and not form controls. I adjusted the code. So, now it should work.

Comment: got this error now Compile error SUB or Function not defined "OLEObjects" is highlighted and yellow thing is on first line on SUB

Comment: @kzhel-farmer: The code works fine here. I just adjusted the code a bit more to go through the `Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects`collection instead of `Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes`as before. Maybe that helps. Again this code also works fine on my end.

Comment: Possibly you want to add `If InStr(1, o.Name, "CheckBox") > 0 Then` as offered in [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927684/unselect-all-checkboxes-from-excel-workbook-with-vba-macro) in order to make sure that this really is a checkbox. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991308/how-do-i-use-checkboxes-in-an-if-then-statement-in-excel-vba-2010) might be also relevant if you are partially using ActiveX controls and partially form controls.

Comment: 'Sub reminder1()
Sheets(1).Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lRow
    For Each shp In Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects
        If shp.Type = 12 And Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address).Row = i Then
            If OLEObjects(shp.Name).Object.Value = True Then
                code here
            End Sub'
i copy paste all this code getting same error compile error just to let you know i have button to run this macro OLEObjects is giving error

Comment: it is completely Active X control check box and have one button to run this macro and other cells just manual entry of names and emails

Comment: i know it is some small error but finding it hard to figure out

Comment: i changed ' If OLEObjects(shp.Name).Object.Value = True Then '  with ' If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(shp.Name).Object.Value = True Then ' not getting error but it is not sending email not doing anything